# Footer appears on top of div | ASP .NET

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The footer of the main page appears just below the autogenerated menu bar at the top of the page and interferes with the div in my main page. It doesn't happen in the other pages which tips me off that something is wrong in the main page but I can't see what that is. Also, when I zoom out the content seems to veer off to the right and I don't know why.

I have given ample bottom margin to the footer and I can see the flex container div doesn't reach all the way to the bottom.

Index.cshtml

```
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #myMap {
            width: 30vw;
            height: 30vh;
        }

        .flex-container {
            margin: auto;
            position: fixed;
            display: flex;
            padding-top: 10px;
            width: 80vw;
            margin-bottom: -115px;
            
        }

        .flex-child {
            flex: 1;
            border: 2px solid yellow;
            width: 49%;
            max-width: 49%;
        }

            .flex-child:first-child {
                margin-right: 20px;
                width: 49%;
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                max-width: 49%;
            }
    </style>

    <!--<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=LoadMap" async defer></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js" defer></script>

</head>

<div class="flex-container">

    <div class="flex-child left">
        <h2>Bing Maps integration in ASP.NET</h2>
        <h4>Select sector:</h4>

        <select id="mapMenu" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px">
            <option value="0">Building</option>
            <option value="1">Machine</option>
            <option value="2">Grid</option>
            <option value="3">IT</option>
            <option value="4">Power</option>
            <option value="5">Platform</option>
        </select>

        <div id="myMap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-child right">
        <div id="infoPane"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - ®</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("My Tool", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Data Entry", "DataEntry", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("View Entries", "ViewEntries", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer style="position:relative; height: 50px; width: 100%;">
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Schneider Electric®</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I added the footer style tags but they did not help. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use the built-in code editor to reproduce your issue? You provided 1 html snippet which contains inline css and an aparant unrelated html snippet which contains no styles. Your question is unclear because the problem cant be observed.

Comment: It's not unrelated. This is .NET - Layout.cshtml gets rendered on every page of the website. The @RenderBody() function there refers to rendering every page's body independently. The footer is in Layout as it is present on every page. :)
I am also not sure I can use the built-in code editor with .NET stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, my hunch was confirmed and the styling of the Layout and Index are interfering.
The solution I found is to replace the footer in Layout with a section using `RenderSection("Footer", false)` and then generate it the section in every page separately by doing:

At bottom of Index.cshtml:

```
...
@section Footer
{
    <footer>...</footer>
}
```

For more info and an example on using `RenderSection()`:
[Here](https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/asp-net-mvc5/asp-net-mvc-5-renderbody-renderpage-and-rendersection-with-example.php)